# Format Float as Int when printing in Haskell

Tags: haskell, printing, int, format

This Haskell program prints "1.0" How can I get it to print "1"?

```
fact 0 = 1
fact x = x * fact (x-1)

place m n = (fact m) / (fact n) * (fact (m-n))

main = do   
   print (place 0 0)
```

Comment: _Don't_ ever calculate nCr this way. It's horribly inefficient, as the factorial generates huge terms which for the result will cancel anyway (which is the only reason why you get theoretically integral result from the formula). The right way is to multiply up only the non-cancelling terms, and not divide anything at all; then you also don't need to worry about floating-point.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, why don't you make that an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By using the `/` operation, you are asking haskell to use a fractional data type. You probably don't want that in this case. It is preferable to use an integral type such as `Int` or `Integer`. So I suggest to do the following:
 1. Add a type declaration for the `fact` function, something like `fact :: Integer -> Integer`
 2. Use `quot` instead of `/`.

So your code should look like this:

```
fact :: Integer -> Integer
fact 0 = 1
fact x = x * fact (x-1)

place :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
place m n = (fact m) `quot` (fact n) * (fact (m-n))

main = do   
   print (place 0 0)
```

Also, as [@leftaroundabout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745903/leftaroundabout) pointed out, you probably want to use a better algorithm for computing those binomial numbers.

Comment: With that factorial formula, you _must_ use `Integer` even when you only expect rather small inputs.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `round`:

`print (round $ place 0 0)`

This changes the formatting to the one you want. redneb's answer is, however, the right approach.